# how to calculate data from socket in server and then return results python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm a newbie in python and I'm stuck in socket problem. So I have an array of string and I want to get the sum of each item. Below is my code and my expected results but I keep getting errors. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Client.py:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("localhost",31415))

testing_strings = ["1 2 3", "4 5 6", "1 2 5"]


for c in testing_strings:
    encoded_message = c.encode()
    sock.sendall(encoded_message)

sock.shutdown(1)

message = ""

encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)
while len(encoded_message) > 0:
    message += "result is: " + encoded_message.decode() + "\n"
    encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)

print(message)
sock.close()
```

Server.py:

```
import socket

listener = socket.socket()
listener.bind(("",31415))
listener.listen()

while 1:
    conn = listener.accept()
    sock = conn[0]

    message  = ""
    sum =0
    encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)
    while len(encoded_message) > 0:
        message += encoded_message.decode()
        y = [float(x) for x in message.split(' ')]
        for x in y:
            sum+= x

        encoded_message = sock.recv(2048)

        sock.sendall(sum.encode())
        sock.close()
```

The expected output would be

```
result is: 6
result is: 15
result is: 8
```

Comment: What do you actually get?  TCP isn't a message-based protocol, so your three sends might result in a single recv of `1 2 34 5 61 2 5`.  `print` what you are receiving and devise a way to make sure you break the messages appropriately.  One way is to send `1 2 3\n`, etc., buffer your reads and extract only complete lines from the data stream.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Now I know how to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

TCP isn't a message-based protocol, so your three sends might result in a single recv of `1 2 34 5 61 2 5`. Print what you are receiving and devise a way to make sure you break the messages appropriately. One way is to send `1 2 3\n`, etc., buffer your reads and extract only complete lines from the data stream.